# Longtable gives error

Tags: longtable

I am trying to draw a long table but get an error:

```
    Command \longtable* already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I checked old questions but couldn't find the solution.

```
    \documentclass[prl,showpacs,superscriptaddress,floatfix,12pt,showkeys,noshowpacs]{revtex4}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{longtable}

    \begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{longtable}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
    \caption{blah}
    \label{tab:eb-eg}
    \toprule 
    {Sys} & {1} & {2} & {3}& {4}  & {5}& {6} & {7} & {8} & {9} & {10} & {11}
    \midrule
{\bf{Sc}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
\hline
{\bf{Ti}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
\hline
{\bf{V}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-in &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & O-out &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
\hline
{\bf{Cr}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Mn}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Fe}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Co}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Ni}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Cu}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
\hline
{\bf{Zn}} &  &  &   &  & & & & & & \\
{} & N-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & N-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-in & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
{} & O-out & -3.01 & 0.70 & -3.36 & 3.50 & 3.36 \\
 \bottomrule

    \end{longtable}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the error you mention. Probably not relevant, but you should be aware that `revtex4` is deprecated and `revtex4-1` should be used.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the helping.
It work only if I exchange the first line with:
        \documentclass[12pt]{article}

Comment: your document example has many errors: (i) the package `booktabs` is missing, (ii) line with `\label{...}` had to be terminated by `\\ ` , (ii) the first tablerow had to be termninated by `\\ `,  (iii) after row with "Cr" are in each row missed ampersands ... correcting all this errors you mwe works with `revtex4` as well as with `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Another error in your code: The `longtable` is set up to contain 11 columns (all of them of type `r`), yet the body of the `longtable` appears to consist of 12 columns.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the points. The problem with \usepackage{longtable} has been solved when I changed the documentclass. I then corrected the other error and everything is perfect now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments